# How to write a stateful background job in ASPNET Boilerplate

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have a ASPNET Boilerplate project with a background job written this way:

```
public class MyJob : BackgroundJob<MyJobInput>, ITransientDependency
{
    public MyJob()
    {
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    public override void Execute(MyJobInput input)
    {
        // Create the TFS release and wait for it to complete
    }
}
```

This job starts a long release in TFS and waits for it to complete. The problem is that if the job starts the TFS release and after a while the backend server is restarted, the job will be restarted and will create a new release.

What I would like to do is let the background job recover the TFS release launched previously (if any) by reading the release ID from the job input data.
This requires that I should be allowed to update the data in the `AbpBackgroundJobs`.`JobArgs` field.

Is there any way to do it? Is this allowed by ABP by design?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" this issue starting the TFS release before enqueuing the background job and putting the release ID in the job inputs. The job is only responsible of following a running release now, not to start a release if none is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can persist your state in a temp database or in a file. So while your release is going on save every step. When the service is being restarted then first read from the persisted data to check your last release state. If it is corrupted then resume if not start over your new release .

Comment: Hi @Alper, thanks for the response. I was looking for a more centralized solution with less work. Keep in mind that at the moment Boilerplate jobs already read the input data from the `AbpBackgroundJobs.JobArgs` field, so it would cost less to update that field instead of starting sa new method of persistence